# Unable to login in manager app in tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, devops, tomcat8

I have installed my tomcat on GCP and configured it with the following settings:

file: `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="vinay" password="s3cret" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

fie: `sudo vi /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml`

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" allow="192\.168\.1\.220|127\.\d+\. \d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /
>
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java
\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

fie: `/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml`

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="^.*$" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java
\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

While I open using port 8080(already configured in VM instance and added firewall rules in GCP account), the login fails. also, there is a warning that `your connection to the site is not private`

Where is the error? Where do i modify to make my server run?